# Space filling function

Tags: fractals

How do I obtain the space filling function (continuous surjection $[0, 1] \to [0, 1]^2$) from a [space filling curve](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/HilbertCurve.html)?

Comment: Is this a math question or a *Mathematica* question?

Comment: This is a Mathematica question. I'd like a function that takes a number $l$, and outputs the coordinates $(x, y)$ on the curve at a distance of $l$ from the start of the curve.

Comment: Are you actually looking for the infinitely-recursed [space-filling curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Space-filling_curve)?  Because for any finite level $n$, the Hilbert curve $H_n$ doesn't actually fill space (it's not a surjection);  but your answer below seems to imply that you're just looking for the points along $H_n$.

Comment: Yes, an infinitely-recursed curve would be best, but an approximation is ok.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Implementing the algorithm found [on Brian Hayes's webpage](http://bit-player.org/2013/mapping-the-hilbert-curve), which takes advantage of the base-4 expansion of a number between 0 and 1:

```
hilbertMap[quadits_List] := hilbertMap[quadits] =
  If[Length[quadits] == 0, {1/2, 1/2},
   Switch[First[quadits],
    0, {{0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0}}.hilbertMap[Drop[quadits, 1]],
    1, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1/2}}.hilbertMap[Drop[quadits, 1]] + {0, 1/2},
    2, {{1/2, 0}, {0, 1/2}}.hilbertMap[Drop[quadits, 1]] + {1/2, 1/2},
    3, -{{0, 1/2}, {1/2, 0}}.hilbertMap[Drop[quadits, 1]] + {1, 1/2}]
   ]
hilbertCoords[x_, prec_] := 
  hilbertMap[IntegerDigits[Floor[x 4^prec], 4]]
```

Briefly: `IntegerDigits[Floor[x 4^prec], 4]` obtains the first `prec` digits of the base-4 expansion of a number between 0 and 1, after the decimal (quartal?) point.  The `hilbertMap` function takes this list of digits and uses the algorithm described by Brian Hayes.  (EDIT:  as pointed out by @MarkMcClure in the comments, this algorithm appeared previously in *Space-Filling Curves* by Hans Sagan.)

The result is accurate to within $\pm 2^{-(\text{prec} + 1)}$;  if a numerical result to within machine precision is needed, `prec` can be set to `$MachinePrecision/Log[10, 2]`.  This algorithm is also significantly faster than the use of the built-in `HilbertCurve`, which calculates all of the points in the curve;  this algorithm effectively only calculates the points that are needed.

Comment: Looks like a direct implementation of the algorithm on page 18 of [Space-Filling Curves](http://link.springer.com/book/10.1007%2F978-1-4612-0871-6) by Hans Sagan; odd that Hayes' page doesn't mention that. It's also worth mentioning that the result can be computed exactly for any rational input. An example is shown in [this response](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/921985/what-is-the-hilbert-curves-equation/1739118#1739118) on math.stackexchange.

Answer (score 1):

A linear interpolation seems to work:

```
toFunction[line_]:=With[{l=Length[line[[1]]],m=Max[line[[1]]]},Interpolation[Table[{(i-1)/(l-1),line[[1]][[i]]/m},{i,1,l}],InterpolationOrder->1]]
f=toFunction[HilbertCurve[6]];

ParametricPlot[f[l],{l,0,1},PerformanceGoal->"Quality",PlotPoints->5000]
```

Comment: Pretty sure you want `InterpolationOrder -> 1` rather than `InterpolationOrder -> 0`.  Look at `Plot[f[l], {l, 0, 0.01}]` in each case and see which one seems more reasonable.

Comment: Yeah, that looks better, thanks!